# How to prevent phpMyAdmin from constantly sending XMLHttpRequests to the web server?

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpMyadmin (4.3.7) sends ajax requests to the webserver. This happens every to seconds. I intercepted one of these requests with burpsuite. This is what phpMyAdmin sends to the server: (I removed some lines.)

> POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>   Referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=dc59d3c70f86fee4d9d5f91673d88927
>   Content-Length: 106
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> ajax_request=true&token=dc59d3c70f86fee4d9d5f91673d88927&db=&access_time=1524&_nocache=1421857738820429740

My MySQL log shows statements like the following each time:

> Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on 
>   Query SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
>   Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
>   Query SHOW TABLES FROM `my_db_name`
>   Query SHOW TABLES FROM `my_db_name`
>   Query SELECT CURRENT_USER()
>   Query SELECT `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`USER_PRIVILEGES` WHERE GRANTEE='''root''@''localhost''' AND PRIVILEGE_TYPE='EVENT'
>   Query SELECT CURRENT_USER()
>   Query SELECT `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`USER_PRIVILEGES` WHERE GRANTEE='''root''@''localhost''' AND PRIVILEGE_TYPE='TRIGGER'
>   Query SHOW TABLES FROM `my_db_name`
>   Query SELECT CURRENT_USER()
>   Query SELECT `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`USER_PRIVILEGES` WHERE GRANTEE='''root''@''localhost''' AND PRIVILEGE_TYPE='EVENT'
>   Query SELECT CURRENT_USER()
>   Query SELECT `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`USER_PRIVILEGES` WHERE GRANTEE='''root''@''localhost''' AND PRIVILEGE_TYPE='TRIGGER'
>   Quit

phpMyAdmin sends these requests when the browser tab that shows phpMyAdmin is not active. When I activate that tab phpMyAdmin stops sending these request. When I switch back to another tab again then phpMyAdmin does *not* start sending them again.

My question is: What can I do so that phpMyAdmin never sends anything to the web server by itself?

Comment: Do you let it finish loading completely before you tab away the first time? Curious if they perhaps use an active window check that fails (since you never let it finish loading on the initial). Just a guess on my part. Also, is this in all browsers or one specific?

Comment: @JClaspill It happens in firefox and opera. The sending of those ajax requests starts randomly. It just starts at a certain point of time x. Then the next request is made at time x + 2 seconds. The next one at time x + 4 seconds and so on. (Sometimes it also happens every three seconds.) Then I activate the tab with phpMyAdmin and the sending of the requests stops. I am not able to tell when the first of these ajax requests is sent. It appears to be completely random to me. It has nothing to do with the fact that the page could be loaded completely. Thanx for your comment.

Comment: From what you say, it sounds like the phpmyadmin is trying to run an active window check. These are known to be somewhat buggy if the page doesn't finish loading prior to losing focus. To be honest, it doesn't even require the page load issue to have problems. Which could explain the fact it is random and hard for you to track down. My first guess would be for you to dig through the js and see if there are any active/focus window checks. I assume the focus/active check or even the setTimeouts for verifying your signed in are all tied to that.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with 4.3.7. Only when I choose something like Status > Monitor do I see  frequent queries.